# Is it possible with Prometheus to send a resolve message by conditional, as Zabbix does?

Tags: prometheus, zabbix, prometheus-alertmanager

You can configure Zabbix at a low value and time, after which an alert will be made as resolved. For example, send an alert message above 95% and send a resolve message after when less 70% for 15 minutes. Is it possible with Prometheus?

## Added alert manager rule:

The main idea is to send an alert if the value is 1, and the same alerts didn't fire for the last hour.
I count alerts to get data. If the value <= 1, then there weren't alerts.

So, I'm not sure if the query is correct, and I need alerts for each `zone`. Because it looks like I calculate all alerts without filtering by `zone`.

query:

```sql
(host_tracker_down{job="donodeexporter", state="down"} >= 1) and on(zone) count_over_time(ALERTS{job="donodeexporter", state="down", alertstate="firing", receiver="emailhosttracker", alertname="HostTrackerSiteDown"}[1h]) <= 1
```

or using `absent_over_time`

```sql
(host_tracker_down{job="donodeexporter", state="down"} >= 1) and on(zone) (absent_over_time(ALERTS{job="donodeexporter", state="down", alertstate="firing", receiver="emailhosttracker", alertname="HostTrackerSiteDown"}[1h]) >= 1)
```

Metrics:

```sql
{__name__="host_tracker_down", instance="mon-prometheus", job="donodeexporter", state="down", zone="111-111.test"}1
```

Comment: If you are using AlertManager, check documentation `send_resolved` https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/

Comment: @SergioSantiago could you take a look, please? I have updated the question.

Comment: Usually it is not the best approach. Ideally you have your alert firing while your query is matching. But keep in mind that it doesn't mean that you will receive multiple alerts. Alert manager can deduplicate and group similar alerts. So, my approach is use the query `host_tracker_down{job="donodeexporter", state="down"} >= 1`  that will keep firing until you fix it and therefore the query doesn't match anymore automatically closing the alert